# How to set Vue.http.post data using Vue to send data to Laravel route?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to send a post request to Laravel backend using Vue.js. I'd like to make it without any extra library. I am making a pure Vue.http.get request and it works like a charm. For testing Laravel route and Controller returned data, I've made a ajax request in my template, which also works fine, returning the correct data. However, when I use Vue, via Vue.http.post('My/Controller/Route',data) it doesn't sends the post data to the Controller.

My Vue.js component:

```
<template>
    <div class="opt-pro" v-for="r in profissionais">
        <input :id="r.id" type="checkbox" :value="r.id" v-model="checkedNames" v-on:change="filterResources()"/><label>  {{ r.title }}</label>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                dados: {view: 'dia', pro: [], data: 'Setembro 11, 2017'},
                meus_recursos: [],
                profissionais: [],
                checkedNames: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getResources: function() {
                var self = this;
                return Vue.http.get('/admin/getResources').then((response) => {
                _.forEach(response.data.resources,function(item){
                    self.meus_recursos.push(item);
                    self.profissionais.push(item);
                });
                console.log(self.meus_recursos);
            });
        },
        filterResources: function(){
            this.dados.pro = this.checkedNames; // returned by another Vue piece of code - console.log() returns the correct data for this var
            return Vue.http.post('/admin/getAgendamentosPorProfissional', this.dados).then(
                (response) => {
                    console.log(response.body);
                }, 
                (response) => {
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(response.body);
                });
        }
    }
```

My Laravel Controller function:

```
public function getAgendamentosPorProfissional(){
       // $view = $_POST['view'];
      // $pro = $_POST['pro'];
      // $data = $_POST['data'];
      $post = $_POST;

      return response()->json(array('post' => $post),200);
}
```

It returns in my console:
    `{post: Array(0)}`

My jQuery AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/admin/getAgendamentosPorProfissional',
      data:  {"data": data, "view": view, "pro": [pro],"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
      success:function(data){
        console.log("AJAX - /admin/getAgendamentosPorProfissional");
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

It returns in my console:

```
post:
    data: "Setembro 11, 2017",
    pro:["75"]
    view:"dia"
    _token:"6LviacS2KoBqjXxTsFhnTtAQePuEzZ49OMwqBmbM"
```

It's not a CORS issue, since it returns the correct data from the requested url in laravel. How can I fix this?

My token is set at laravel/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);
    next();
});
```

Comment: Is there a method name missing?

Comment: @Bert, yes, there are a bunch of other methods in the component, they all work fine. My problem is only with this piece of code

Comment: I meant that the code you posted inside `methods` is not contained in a method. It should be. I assume it is correctly formatted in the code somewhere or the post would never be made.

Comment: @Bert and it needs to be `methods` not `method`

Comment: I think the main difference I see between VueResource post and the jQuery post is that the `_token` is part of the data submission in the jQuery version but not the VueResource version.

Comment: @Bert, I've edited the question, the token is set.

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in your browser to look at the actual post? Possibly a clue there. Otherwise I can't see the problem so far. The `Laravel` global is set somewhere?

Comment: @Bert, yes, the code is programmed to work with laravel, that's why the get function works fine... and also the AJAX request. If it wasn't working, if it was a Laravel issue, it wouldn't return data to browser. Both returned data values are printed in my console.